# R Shiny Apps Greys Out and Hangs

Tags: javascript, r, sockets, shiny

It seems that on occasion my R Shiny app appears to grey out and hang when a user first hits the site. I believe this happens because their previous web socket connection didn’t successfully terminate and R is unable to establish a new connection. I see this error in the JS console when it happens:
shinyapp.js:310 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of null. The app works fine locally, yet when I deploy it on the cloud this issue occurs.

I am not sure if the issue is related to what is described here:
https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r/issues/97

Comment: I am having the same issue. My app works fine locally, but when deployed on a server I get the same error message. I am working on a CentOS 7 server using R 3.6.1 and shiny-server1.5.9.923. Did you ever figure out the issue?

Comment: The issue actually was related to my startup. Shiny couldn't connect to my persisted data store so the app crashed. I suggest you check your logs and you will most likely see an error that is causing the app to crash

Comment: Hi ! Did you find a solution to this issue ? I have exactly the same error message when trying to reach the app from remote client. What is even more strange is the fact that is works on certain clients but crashes on others...

Comment: The way the app is deployed could be of some help. For instance, Docker can give logs about the error, using "docker logs <container>" (according to my memory)

Comment: We need some info about the startup, the connections and the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I found it difficult to debug my shiny app when it was deployed on a server like CentOS where the logs don't display everything. My solution was to try and deploy the application through [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/) to debug. This way you can use RStudio to error check what's happening while loading your application online.

In my case, it was an issue with `renv` not being able to load packages that would load fine locally, but I wouldn't get this error in the logs trying to load the application in CentOS. I could see the error better after running `rsconnect::showLogs()` once it was on the shinyapps server.